# Handling images in a proxy server written in C

Tags: c, proxy, network-programming

To receive from the requested web server and transmit it to the client, I am doing the following,

```
while(1) {
        bzero(buffer,65536); //Character buffer of 64KB
        ret_val = recv(sockfd, buffer, 65535,0); //sockfd is the socket between web server and proxy server
        if(ret_val < 0) 
            error("Error Reading data from requested server");
        send_ret_val = send_all(sock, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);//sockfd is socket between proxy server and client 
        if(send_ret_val < 0) 
          error("Error returning data to client");
        if(ret_val == 0)
            break;
}
```

The function send() all transmits all the data there in the buffer and returns 0 else returns a negative value for an error.

The problem is that the server seems to be working fine for text data but cannot handle images and other binary data. When using firefox, I get the error, incompatible compression technique.

Is there a problem in this code or is there a problem somewhere else?

Answer (score 3):

`strlen(buffer)` truncates when it found null character in the buffer.
Image data is binary data. Binary data may contain null characters in the middle of the image.
You must use the number of bytes received from the recv call to send bytes to client.

Modify following statement

```
send_ret_val = send_all(sock, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
```

to

```
send_ret_val = send_all(sock, buffer, ret_val, 0);
```

Comment: If you do this, you can also remove the call to `bzero`, because there's no reason the buffer would need to be filled with zeroes.

Comment: @Gangadhar In the middle of the *image.* It's an image. Not text.

Answer (score 0):

> Handling images in a proxy server written in C

... is no different from handling any other type of data. If it doesn't work for images, it will break for other kinds of data as well.

```
    bzero(buffer,65536); //Character buffer of 64KB
```

Cargo-cult programming. Remove it.

```
    ret_val = recv(sockfd, buffer, 65535,0); //sockfd is the socket between web server and proxy server
```

There's no reason for the length supplied to be different from `sizeof buffer` here.

```
    if(ret_val < 0) 
        error("Error Reading data from requested server");
```

This is only OK if `error()` prints or accesses `errno` prior to executing any other system calls, and if it magically causes this loop to exit. After this you need to add:

```
else if (retval == 0)
    break;    // end of stream
```

Then:

```
    send_ret_val = send_all(sock, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);//sockfd is socket between proxy server and client
```

This assumes that the data received is null-terminated, which isn't even valid in the case of a text message. It is completely wrong in the case of an image. Change to:

```
    send_ret_val = send_all(sock, buffer, retval , 0);//sockfd is socket between proxy server and client 

    if(send_ret_val < 0) 
      error("Error returning data to client");
```

Again this is only OK if `error()` prints or accesses `errno` prior to executing any other system calls, and if it magically causes this loop to exit.

```
    if(ret_val == 0)
        break;
```

You have this in the wrong place.

> The function send() all transmits all the data there in the buffer and returns 0 else returns a negative value for an error.

No. It returns -1 or the number of bytes transferred. The only way it can return zero is if you supplied a zero length, which would be completely pointless.